# Programa em C++ para de responder ao chamar uma função pela segunda vez

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo um joguinho simplificado no estilo do Pokémon, porém está parando de responder ao chamar InicializaPokemon pela segunda vez, não estou encontrando o problema porque funciona normalmente com o primeiro e trava no segundo.

[image: Print mostrando que o jogo parou de funcionar]

O print dos valores é só pra testar se está tudo sendo passado corretamente.

Trechos do código:

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    TipoMove flamethrower; 
    TipoMove fire_blast; 
    TipoMove fly; 
    TipoMove earthquake;

    TipoMove quick_attack;
    TipoMove thunderbolt;
    TipoMove thunder;
    TipoMove skull_bash;

    InicializaMove(&flamethrower, "Flamethrower", 1, 'e', 95); 
    InicializaMove(&fire_blast, "Fire Blast", 2, 'e', 120);
    InicializaMove(&fly, "Fly", 3, 'f', 70);
    InicializaMove(&earthquake, "Earthquake", 4, 'f', 100);

    InicializaMove(&quick_attack, "Quick Attack", 5, 'f', 40);
    InicializaMove(&thunderbolt, "Thunderbolt", 6, 'e', 95);
    InicializaMove(&thunder, "Thunder", 7, 'e', 120);
    InicializaMove(&skull_bash, "Skull Bash", 8, 'f', 100);

    TipoPokemon charizard;
    TipoPokemon pikachu;

    InicializaPokemon(&charizard, 2, "Charizard", 293, 280, 360, 328, 348, 295, flamethrower, fire_blast, fly, earthquake);

    ImprimePokemon(&charizard);

    InicializaPokemon(&pikachu, 1, "pikachu", 229, 196, 274, 306, 218, 218, quick_attack, thunderbolt, thunder, skull_bash);

    ImprimePokemon(&pikachu);


    return 0;
}
```

InicializaPokemon:

```
void InicializaPokemon(TipoPokemon *poke, int id, string nome, float ataque, float defesa, float vida, float velocidade, float spAtk, float spDef, TipoMove mov0, TipoMove mov1, TipoMove mov2, TipoMove mov3){         

    poke->id = id;
    poke->nome = nome;
    poke->atk = ataque;
    poke->def = defesa;
    poke->hp = vida;
    poke->speed = velocidade;
    poke->sp_atk = spAtk;
    poke->sp_def = spDef;
    poke->moves[0]= mov0;
    poke->moves[1] = mov1;
    poke->moves[2] = mov2;
    poke->moves[3] = mov3;                                                                              
}
```

InicializaMove:

```
void InicializaMove(TipoMove *mov, string n, int id, char t, float pw){
    mov->nome = n;
    mov->id = id;
    mov->tipo = t;
    mov->power = pw;

    cout << "move " << mov->nome << " inicializado " << endl;
}
```

[Código completo no Github](https://github.com/leilaapsilva/poke/blob/master/jogo.cpp)

Comment: Na estrutura tem `TipoMove moves[3];`, quando devia ter tamanho `4`, pois você utiliza 4 *moves*

Comment: @Isac mas em C vetores começam na posição 0... C++ não é assim também?

Comment: Exato. Em um vetor de tamanho 3, só existem as posições 0, 1 e 2. Não existe posição 3. Por isso a falha de segmentação no teu programa.

Comment: Nossa, mudei aqui e realmente funcionou, acabei me confundindo com isso, obrigada :D

Comment: Já agora para que consiga saber como resolver no futuro, o que eu fiz foi colar o código no codeblocks corri e vi onde crashou, que era na linha `poke->moves[3] = mov3;`, e por dedução se crasha ai é porque o tamanho não joga com os valores atribuídos.

Comment: Também era boa ideia initcializar os objectos apenas nos construtores, pois aí garantes que estás a atribuir valores em objectos que realmente existem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão já foi respondida nos comentários, mas apenas para contextualizar um pouco:

### Comportamento Indefinido

Você acabou de se deparar com um **Comportamento Indefinido**. Esse tipo de comportamento ocorre quando o programador (nós) comete um equívoco que o compilador não é obrigado a diagnosticar.

No seu caso específico, o erro era uma tentativa de acesso fora dos limites de uma array. Note que não necessariamente acontecerá um erro, e, caso ocorra um (Como uma falha de segmentação), um depurador não necessariamente apontará a causa correta.

### Como se proteger desse tipo de erro?

Primeiro, ligando as warnings do compilador (E levando elas a sério!). No caso do gcc, deve-se setar a flag `-Wall`.

Segundo, utilizando interfaces mais seguras. No seu caso específico, seria mais interessante utilizar um [std::array](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) ao invés de uma lista simples, e utilizar a função-membro [at()](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) ao invés do `operator[]` para recuperar/modificar os elementos, pois essa função realiza a verificação de limites, evitando que seu programa cause comportamento indefinido.

Comment: Funções membro `at()` adicionam um overhead em todo acesso de índices (a checagem do índice estar dentro dos limites é um código condicional), então é mais interessante usar iteradores, que garantem o limite e o overhead da checagem é melhor aprendido pela CPU.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Obrigado pelo comentário! No caso dela, iteradores não ajudam, pois cada elemento é acessado diretamente. Também, o overhead da função-membro `at()` é mínimo: Não vale a pena tentar otimizar um programa dessa forma sem medir a performance e detectar que tal função é um bottleneck significativo. Finalmente, na maior parte dos casos (Quando o compilador pode provar que um acesso ilegal não acontece) essa checagem é removida pelo otimizador. [Esse teste](https://godbolt.org/g/6AiAPb) mostra isso. Verifique que não há saltos condicionais no programa compilado.